# Defiant.js Search with String that includes Escape Sequences

Tags: javascript

So I'm having the string: `var str = "this is the \"end\"";` that I want to search against lets say:

```
search = {}
search.inhere = [{label: "this is the \"beginning\""},{label: "this is the \"end\""}];
```

`JSON.search(search, '//inhere[label"' + str + '"]');` will return an `INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR` which seems logical, since str will only consist of the quotes without backslashes when executed. However, should it be feasible to simply substitute `\"` by `\\\"`? I did that with `str.split("\"").join("\\\"")` but that still returns `INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR`.

Comment: Notice that you're not searching for an escape sequence, you're just searching for a quote.

Comment: It seems no escape characters are supported at all: https://github.com/hbi99/defiant.js/issues/9. Try to file a bug/feature request.